# Gulp Ruby Sass - RegexpError: failed to allocate memory :/\n.*/

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, node.js, gulp, gulp-sass

I have installed Gulp on my project and was working perfectly.

Today when I run **gulp build** the project it is giving error: **gulp plugin ruby sass.**

The following message appears:

```
Error in plugin 36mgulp-ruby-sass-39m 

RegexpError: failed to allocated memory: /\n.*/
```

***see the image below with the error:**

[image]

Any ideas?

Please help me, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What was causing this was a problem within the file **.sass**

Inside the **.sass** i wrote a review that used accent on the letter "a". Each time I saved the file during development sass did not interpret the accent and then generated special characters:

```
Oo £ ├ÂÔö £ ├éÔö¼├║├ö├Â┬ú
```

The problem was that many, many special characters were generated by loading the file and others can not even be compiled. I realized this when a "trial and error" removing file by file.

So stay tuned to special characters with accents and comments within your **.sass** file, it may generate memory overload problem because of the sheer amount of characters that are generated each time the document is saved.

Comment: So, generally, this kind of error is in something you did and gulp can't compile, nice...